# "cannot read property length of null" - Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-api

I am writing a simple application using Flask. I am using Google API for drawing graphs. The first page displays correctly.

[image: Correct output]

But in the next pages I am getting "cannot read property length of null" error.

[image: Error]

My Code is as shown below:

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100; URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000/">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/new.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="static/lib/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/Chart.js-master/Chart.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload = onLoading()>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="page-header">
          <h3><b>Test</b></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
          <nav>
            <ul class="control-box pager">
              <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
              <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <!-- /.control-box -->
          <!-- Slide1 -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" id="imp">
            <!-- /Slide1 -->
          </div><!-- /Carousel inner -->
        </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->
      </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      // Carousel Auto-Cycle
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 3000
        })
      });

      function onLoading() {
        //alert("Inside");      
        $.get("/load",function(calldata,status) {
          //console.log(calldata);
          //alert(calldata.length);
          var num_nodes = calldata.length;
          var loop = 0;

          for (i=0;i<num_nodes;i++) {
            if (i%4==0) {
              if (i==0) {
                var divoutput = document.getElementById("imp");
                var divhtml = '<div class="item active" id="c'+(i/4)+'"></div>';
                divoutput.innerHTML = divoutput.innerHTML+divhtml;
                alert(i);
                console.log(divoutput.innerHTML);
              } else {
                var divoutput = document.getElementById("imp");
                var divhtml = '<div class="item" id="c'+(i/4)+'"></div>';
                divoutput.innerHTML = divoutput.innerHTML+divhtml;
                loop = i/4;
                alert(loop);
                console.log(divoutput.innerHTML);
              }
            }
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Errors');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Statistics');
            data.addRows([
              ['Success',     calldata[i].errors.success],
              ['Authorization Failure', calldata[i].errors.auth_failure],
              ['Feature Failure',  calldata[i].errors.feature_failure],
              ['FSOL Failure', calldata[i].errors.fsol_failure]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: calldata[i].node_name,
              is3D: true,
              backgroundColor:'#ECECEA',
            };

            var output = document.getElementById("c"+loop);
            //alert("***"+document.getElementById("c"+loop));
            var html = '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="fff"><div class="thumbnail" id="i'+i+'"></div></div></div>';
            //alert(html);
            output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + html;
            var tmp = "i";
            var ele_id = tmp.concat(i);
            //alert(ele_id);
            if (calldata[i].errors.success < calldata[i].errors.auth_failure) {
              document.getElementById("i"+i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(ele_id,data,options));
          }
        });
      }

      function drawChart(ele_id,data,options)
      {
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        //alert(ele_id);  
        //alert("draw"+document.getElementById(ele_id));
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(ele_id));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: error at which line?

Comment: calldata might be null when you are calling get for "load".

Comment: I am not getting error in my console rather it is showing error in the box instead of showing my graph. First page is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @ParkashKumar First slider is perfectly fine. But the next slider is throwing this error.

Comment: Debug through your get method and check if it is null for the n-time?

Comment: I am getting all data at once. So, there is no question of null. Moreover, when I am displaying all the charts in the same page I am not getting any error. It is happening only when I am drawing them in different sliders.

Comment: @ParkashKumar Please see the images

Comment: @vijayP Please see the images

Answer (score 2):

I use bootstrap tabs and want to display a graph on a hidden tab and I get the same error as you

When I display the graph on an active table it show's up perfectly.

So I guess there is something linked to the DOM and hidden elements nothing to do with your data